# My jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a freshman in ICT course, and we have a project.

I am currently working for my jQuery code for add cart. When I choose how many I'll buy for example 5, when I click add cart, the total result will appear to the text field. For some reason, it won't work. I already tried JavaScript but it also won't work.

Here is my code:

```js
 $(function() {
  var $myNumber = $("#myNumber");
  var $add = $("#add");

  $add.click(function() {
    var input = $myNumber.val();
    $('#item').val($(input).val() * $('5000').val());

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="item" readonly>
  <input type="number" id="myNumber" min="1" max="5">
  <button type="button" class="button" id="add">Add Cart</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="Reor">ReOrder</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

For some reason the result that will come out is NaN. What did I miss? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The best advice we can really give you is: next time plan your time better. Also look up what [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) means, and then work backwards to find out why the result is `NaN`.

Comment: `$('5000').val()` - What the heck is that? I'm guessing you don't have `<5000 />` tags. You get NaN because you multiply undefined by a string.

Comment: Im a student and I have some minor subjects too. Here in the philippines its already the end for the 1st term . Projects has been piled up. I am working this project for almost the whole month and im close at finishing it. Just need to solve this problem then I;m already done.

Comment: you dont need to do $('5000').val().You can directly give 5000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
$('#item').val($(input).val() * $('5000').val());
```

You don't have to use `$('5000')` ... just use plain integer values to make a calculation.
You already saved the value to the `input` variable (`input` contains a number already) ... you can use this variable to multiply it with 5000.

```
$('#item').val(input * 5000);
```

```js
 $(function() {
  var $add = $("#add");

  $add.click(function() {
    var input = parseInt($("#myNumber").val(),0);
    $('#item').val(input * 5000);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="item" readonly>
  <input type="number" id="myNumber" min="1" max="5">
  <button type="button" class="button" id="add">Add Cart</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="Reor">ReOrder</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

edit:
Use `parseInt()` on your value! `value` is of type `string`.

```
var input = parseInt($myNumber.val(),0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do have to wrap everything with $()? just

> input *5000

```
$(function() {
  var $myNumber = $("#myNumber");
  var $add = $("#add");

  $add.click(function() {
    var input = $myNumber.val();
    $('#item').val(input * 5000);

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have $('5000').val(),you dont need it
check the following snippet

```js
 $(function() {
  var $myNumber = $("#myNumber");
  var $add = $("#add");

  $add.click(function() {
    var input = parseInt($myNumber.val(),10);
    $('#item').val(input * 5000);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="item" readonly>
  <input type="number" id="myNumber" min="1" max="5">
  <button type="button" class="button" id="add">Add Cart</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="Reor">ReOrder</button>
```

Use parseInt ,to convert your input to a number
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

On input you already have the value of the #myInput element and $('5000') is not needed. Just use the number.

Try this:

```js
 $(function() {
  var $myNumber = $("#myNumber");
  var $add = $("#add");

  $add.click(function() {
    var input = $myNumber.val();
    $('#item').val(input * 5000);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="item" readonly>
  <input type="number" id="myNumber" min="1" max="5">
  <button type="button" class="button" id="add">Add Cart</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="Reor">ReOrder</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```